# Problem: The current div disappears when the task inside it is done

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

here is my HTML:

```
<form action="index.php" method='post'>
<div class="task-btn">
    <button class="task-info" name="update-animal" onclick="show('update')">Update</button>
    <button class="task-info" name="add-animal" onclick="show('add')">Add</button>
    <button class="task-info" name="dlt-animal" onclick="show('delete')">delete</button>
</div>
<?php if($template == 1): ?>
    <div id="update">
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($template == 2): ?>
    <div id="add">
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($template == 3): ?>
    <div id="delete">
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is my php:

```
$template = 0;
if (isset($_POST['update-animal'])) {
$template = 1;
}
if (isset($_POST['add-animal'])) {
$template = 2;
}
if (isset($_POST['dlt-animal'])) {
$template = 3;
}
```

here is my Javascript:

```
 var update = document.getElementById('update');
var add = document.getElementById('add');
var dlt = document.getElementById('delete');


function show(element) {
    if(element == 'update'){
        update.style.display = 'block';
        add.style.display = 'none';
        dlt.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(element == 'add'){
        add.style.display = 'block';
        update.style.display = 'none';
        dlt.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(element == 'delete'){
        dlt.style.display = 'block';
        update.style.display = 'none';
        add.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

What i want is to click on the tasks-button and display the respective template. The problem is when I update/add/delete some data from my Database it refresh the page so it will display just the three button and not the content of the div you were on.
If you need the php for the add div to see what's going on, just tell me I will send it.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear, what exactly do you expact to see as a result of clicking any of the buttons? Apart from that, you repeat id="updated" 3 times, is this what you want?

Comment: I've made a mistake in the name of the classes for the divs, im gonna edit it to fix that error. but my problem is that when i click on the task button add-animal and I perfectly add the animal's info into the database there should be an message in the add-animal div that tell us that everything went well, but instead the page refresh itself and I dont know if everything went fine or not. Do you want me to post the code for my add-animal div?

Comment: If success message is all that is in the add-animal div then no need to post it. You have two options here: pass parameter to url (for example ?success=true) and access it after page refresh or don't refresh and use ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Got your problem. You don't want to refresh the page after the task done.
So into the `onclick` before the function name add `return`. The function should return false to the onclick. That means in HTML part change your button part code with this:

```
<button class="task-info" name="update-animal" onclick="return show('update')">Update</button>
<button class="task-info" name="add-animal" onclick="return show('add')">Add</button>
<button class="task-info" name="dlt-animal" onclick="return show('delete')">delete</button>
```

Then in javascript function just add `return false;` end of function like this:

```
function show(element) {
 if(element == 'update'){
        update.style.display = 'block';
        add.style.display = 'none';
        dlt.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(element == 'add'){
        add.style.display = 'block';
        update.style.display = 'none';
        dlt.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(element == 'delete'){
        dlt.style.display = 'block';
        update.style.display = 'none';
        add.style.display = 'none';
    }
return false;
}
```